# new Date() in wrong time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, isodate

At the time of this post my current time is `2017-01-10T19:23:00.000Z`
 but `new Date()` gives me `2017-01-11T00:23:19.521Z` 5 hours ahead of my current timezone. This affects the way my data is stored in my MongoDB. I know I can set the time to 5 hours ago using

```
var datetime    = new Date();
 datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours()-5);
```

But I will prefer a better way to do this. [I tried using this.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_toisostring) I still got the same time. In other parts of my code I get `Tue Jan 10 2017 19:54:30 GMT-0500 (EST)` different from the initial time. I will be happy if someone can point out what's wrong here.

Comment: Maybe try .toLocaleString() or something like new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))

Comment: @aggaton Thanks for your response. I used `new Date().toLocaleString();` and I got `1/10/2017, 8:20:30 PM ` not exactly what I'm looking for. I will like the time in `TZ` format. However `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` gave an error of `year is not defined`

Comment: Um, the time of your post is `2017-01-11 00:56:01Z`. No idea where you lost one and a half hours?

Comment: Obviously I spent the time trying to make sure the post was well explanatory while searching through suggested answers to my question. Do you have a solution or you're trying to be funny?

Comment: It seems your times are correct, you just don't realize it's in UTC (that's what the `Z` means). The one is formatted using `.toUTCString()` (or `.toISOString()`), the other is formatted using `.toString()` which does output your local timezone. They might be represented by the same `Date` object; and no, this does not affect how they are stored in MongoDB.

Comment: @Bergi so this is purely a format issue ? I initially tried to query my database using  local time and it returned nothing since my collection was using UTC. My MongoDB collection is like this `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("58758246b67c161ac8479489"),
 "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-11T00:54:30.241Z"),
 "temperature" : 19,
 "humidity" : 23
}`

Comment: Yes, timezones are entirely a formatting issue. In JavaScript, every `Date` object is just a number (milliseconds since epoch). You need to parse and format appropriately for the timezone you want.

Comment: I agree. As per my MongoDB storing in UTC. How can I query that? This gave me a tough time today. I couldn't find any data for the period I was searching for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is the easiest way to accomplish what you are asking.

```
moment().format() // "2017-01-11T13:56:15-05:00"
```

The output is a string in ISO-8601 format, with time zone offset in effect in your local time zone.

You could do this yourself with a lot of code that reads the various properties of the `Date` object, building a string from those values.  But it is not built-in to the `Date` object in this way.

Also, note any time you try to adjust a `Date` object by a time zone offset, you are simply picking a different point in time.  You're not actually changing the behavior of the time zone being used by the Date object.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think I will use moment.js.

Comment: moment is the way to go.

Comment: sadly this does not help if i need to create a date inputting day,month,year,hour, minute

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any exteral JS file, You can simply use following code to get current timezone.

```
new Date().toString();
```